# How to remove element inside CDATA using xslt

Tags: xml, xslt, cdata

**My xml looks like:**

```
`          <validationRules>
            <rule exceptionText=""
                  format="ECIM_Schematron_1.0"
                  name="dependencies"><![CDATA[<schema xmlns="http://purl.oclc.org/dsdl/schematron">
<pattern>
<rule context="/abc/mno/lpd/Mmt/BusyAnnouncementName">
<assert test='(string-length(@BusyAnnouncementName) = 0 or @BusyAnnouncementName = Ga/GaAnn/@GaAnn)'>Instance of GaAnn with <value-of select="./@BusyAnnouncementName"/> referenced in BusyAnnouncementName must exist.</assert>
</rule>
<rule context="/abc/mno/lpd/Mmt/GenericFailureAnnouncementName">
<assert test='(string-length(@GenericFailureAnnouncementName) = 0 or @GenericFailureAnnouncementName= Ga/GaAnn/@GaAnn)'>Instance of GaAnn with <value-of select="./@GenericFailureAnnouncementName"/> referenced in GenericFailureAnnouncementName must exist.</assert>
</rule>
</pattern>
</schema>]]></rule>
         </validationRules>`
```

**I am expecting a output:**

```
          `<validationRules>
            <rule exceptionText=""
                  format="ECIM_Schematron_1.0"
                  name="dependencies"><![CDATA[<schema xmlns="http://purl.oclc.org/dsdl/schematron">
<pattern>
<rule context="/abc/mno/lpd/Mmt/BusyAnnouncementName">
<assert test='(string-length(@BusyAnnouncementName) = 0 or @BusyAnnouncementName = Ga/GaAnn/@GaAnn)'>Instance of GaAnn with <value-of select="./@BusyAnnouncementName"/> referenced in BusyAnnouncementName must exist.</assert>
</rule>
</pattern>
</schema>]]></rule>
         </validationRules> `
```

I want to remove the rule in which context ends with GenericFailureAnnouncementName inside CDATA using in XSLT script

I tried removing CDATA first and planned to remove the rule.It didnt works

`<xsl:template match="//validationRules/rule/text()">         <xsl:value-of select="." disable-output-escaping="yes"/>   </xsl:template>`

with this I was able to acheive removing CDATA and rest all looks like a TAG

then I tried `<xsl:template match="//rule[ends-with(@context, 'GenericFailureAnnouncementName ')]"/>`
Not able to remove particular rule which is inside CDATA.

Looking for better solutions

Comment: This is only possible with XSLT-3.0. If you don't have the ability to use this version, it's an impossible task to achieve this in one step.

Comment: It is NOT impossible in earlier versions - only more difficult.

Answer (score 1):

As you were told in a comment, with pure XSLT this is feasible mainly in XSLT 3 making use of the `parse-xml` function and the `serialize` function:

```
<xsl:stylesheet xmlns:xsl="http://www.w3.org/1999/XSL/Transform"
    xmlns:xs="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema"
    xmlns:sch="http://purl.oclc.org/dsdl/schematron"
    exclude-result-prefixes="#all"
    version="3.0">

  <xsl:mode on-no-match="shallow-copy"/>
  
  <xsl:output cdata-section-elements="rule"/>

  <xsl:template match="rule">
    <xsl:copy>
      <xsl:apply-templates select="@*"/>
      <xsl:variable name="transformed">
        <xsl:apply-templates select="parse-xml(.)"/>
      </xsl:variable>
      <xsl:value-of select="serialize($transformed)"/>
    </xsl:copy>
  </xsl:template>
  
  <xsl:template match="sch:rule[ends-with(@context, 'GenericFailureAnnouncementName')]"/>
  
</xsl:stylesheet>
```

With earlier versions of XSLT you would need to check whether the processor exposes extension functions or allows you to call into the underlying platform to implement the `parse-xml` and the `serialize` function.

Comment: It is certainly possible in earlier versions too, using only "pure" XSLT   - it just takes more work.

Comment: @michael.hor257k, well, I have changed the wording but I don't think people will show up to present both a pluggable XML parser and an XML serializer implementation for XSLT 1 done in XSLT 1 to prove your point. And I certainly won't consider using some substring searching and replacement in the CDATA section a working solution for that general problem.

Comment: Not sure what you mean by "a pluggable XML parser" or why would such thing be necessary. As for serializing, a solution already exists. I agree that string manipulation is the least attractive alternative.

Comment: @MartinHonnen, for using XSLT-3.0 , We need Saxon-PE which I need license to use .
We are trying to acheive in XSLT -2.0. After removing CDATA, now schema,pattern,rule all becomes tag.. still I am not able to remove one particular rule when it becomes a tag not a text in CDATA

Comment: @ValliAnnamalai, nonsense, Saxon 9.8 HE and later support XSLT 3, as does SaxonJS, SaxonC HE, so you don't need PE or EE or buy a license to use XSLT 3 with any of the features I used in my posted answer.